# Unable to update a particular column on SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been trying to update on of my column in my database named COLUMN_NAME_PERIOD_END but it doesn't seem to be able to.

```
String[] endDate = new String[1];
endDate[0] = paraPeriodDetailsPojoObj.getPeriodEndDate();

Log.d("PeriodEnd.onClick()", "Date: " + endDate[0]);

/*UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
*/

sqliteDatabase.update(DBStorage.TABLE_NAME_PERIODSTART, contentValues, DBStorage.COLUMN_NAME_PERIOD_END+"=?", endDate);
```

No error messages were displayed so I suppose it is my update statement that is having errors. :(

Comment: How about some error checking?

Comment: may be query doesnt meet the WHERE condition? (no record contains `endDate[0]`)

Comment: how about trying `cursor` for `update`?

Comment: so my query above basically means that i am trying to "UPDATE period_startdate SET period_end_column= content values where period_end_column = endDate" ? I am rather confused :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

So, you are putting the array of `contentValues` (which you don't show, so the problem could be there) into the table defined by `TABLE_NAME_PERIODSTART`, and selecting which record to update by searching the column defined by `COLUMN_NAME_PERIOD_END` which must equal `endDate`.

The way I read your question title I'm under the impression you actually want to update the `COLUMN_NAME_PERIOD_END` column with the endDate...  if that's the case your SQL is incorrect.

Otherwise, some possibilities that leap to mind to look for are:

1) Constraints... do you have a `not null` field defined and you are trying to update with a null?
2) Your date format from the program is differing from the one in the database
3) There is no matching record for the endDate you are searching for in the DB

Comment: Yes, I want to update my column_name_period_end with the endDate. The query that I want to use is basically just "UPDATE period_startdate SET period_end_column='29-06-2012';" But I do not know understand how do i implement it into sqlitedatabase.update.

Comment: where the '29-06-2012' is basically retrieved from endDate[0]

Comment: HI EVERYBODY! I have solved my own question. thank you all for the big big help :)